# Was Hagar from Shem, Cham, or Yefes?

Tags: rashi, vayera, genealogy, parashat-chaye-sara

Was Hagar from Shem, Cham, or Yefes? If we say she was from Cham, then how can this be understood in light of Avraham's going out of his way to make sure his descendants don't marry into the descendants of Cham? According to Rashi, he even took her back after Sarah's death.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10921/if-ketura-wasnt-hagar-who-was-she

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Chida in Sefer Devash L'Pi 1:24 says that Hagar came from Cham.

Regarding your question "how can this be understood in light of Avraham's going out of his way to make sure his descendants don't marry into the descendants of Cham?" A look at the verses in Braishis does not mention Cham, it only mentions Canaan. [(Breishis 24:3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=292&hilite=). Rashi explains that since Canaan was cursed, one that is blessed does not stick with one that is cursed. Looking in [Parshas Noach 9:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=142) only Canaan was cursed, not all of Cham's offspring. Hagar although she was from Cham, most likely was not from the offspring of Canaan, more likely she was from the offspring of Mitzrayim, a different son of Cham who was not cursed.

Comment: strange that Noach cursed Canaan for something Cham did.

Comment: @Ray: According to many Mifarshim Cham instigated what was done, and therefore he was cursed.

Comment: you mean Cham alone was cursed and also his future descendant Canaan only?

Comment: @Ray: Look in Rashi in the Parshas Noach link to my answer. Rashi indicates that only Canaan was cursed. It seems like Noach did not curse Cham at all, only his son Canaan.

Comment: I see. Rashi on 9:22 says Cham either castrated him... and in 9:25 Canaan merely told his father. seems strange that Canaan's act was more deserving of the curse.

Comment: @ray, really a separate question, but Rashi says that he cursed Cham's fourth son in retaliation to the fact that Cham prevented Noach from having a fourth son (that was his intention - to prevent further competition for control of the earth).

Answer (score 2):

According to the following Hebrew article Hagar was Cham's daughter:

http://www.biu.ac.il/jh/parasha/sarah/sha.html

Comment: so Cham was pharaoh?

Comment: this doesnt answer the second part of the question which is really the main question

Answer (score 1):

**מדרש רבה מב:ב**
הגר בתו של פרעה היתה

Comment: and what was paroh from? Cham?

Comment: @ray Probably. וּבְנֵי, חָם--כּוּשׁ וּמִצְרַיִם, וּפוּט וּכְנָעַן.