# What does the Zohar say about Ketura? (What are the instances of קְטוּרָה Keturah?)

Tags: zohar, parashat-chaye-sara

What does the Zohar say about Keturah?
More specifically, where are the instances of "Keturah" and what is discussed there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**==זהר חלק א==**
===חיי שרה -- מדרשּ הנעלם===

דף קכט ע"א

- וַיּוֹסֶף אַבְרָהָם וַיִּקַּח אִשָּׁה וּשְׁמָהּ **קְטוּרָה**. וּלְשִׁקּוּלָא דְדַעְתָּא כָּל פָּרְשָׁתָא דָא לִיסְתּוּרֵי.

  [Said R' Yehuda] "Then again Abraham took a wife and her name was **Keturah**." (Gen. 25:1) To a reasonable mind, this whole text is contradictory...

   R' Yehuda, R' Yeysa and R' Chiyya go out (to get the answer taught by the Friends, the masters of Mishna) and find R' Elazar b'R' Shimon, who explains the secret of the tefilin...

דף קכט ע"א-ב

- אָמַר רִבִּי יְהוּדָה אִלְמָלֵא לָא אָתֵינָא אֶלָּא בְּדִיל רָזָא דָא דַּיַּי. אָמְרוּ לֵיהּ זַכָּאָה חוּלָקָךְ לְעַלְמָא דְאָתֵי דְּכָל רָז לָא אָנִיס לָךְ. אָמְרוּ לֵיהּ אָתֵינָא קַמֵּיהּ דְּמַר לְמִנְדַע רָזָא דְהַאי פְּסוּקָא וַיּוֹסֶף אַבְרָהָם וַיִּקַּח אִשָּׁה וּשְׁמָהּ **קְטוּרָה**.

  Rabbi Yehuda said, Even if we came only for this secret [of tefilin], it would have sufficed. They said to him, Happy is your lot in the world to come, for no secret is withheld from you. They said to him, We came before you, Sir, to know the secret of the verse: "Then again Avraham took a wife, and her name was **Kturah**."

See [here for the continuation](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.130b.92?lang=bi), where Abraham, Yitzchaq, are aspects of Soul, and the wives Sarah etc. are aspects of Body, amidst a discussion of the Resurrection and repentance, driving away [Ketura's sons] Zimran and Yokshan [evil deeds] from the world, and Yitzchak dwelling in B'er l'chai ro'i (the Well of Life and Vision [of righteousness])...

דף קלג ע"ב

- וַיּוֹסֶף אַבְרָהָם וַיִּקַּח אִשָּׁה וּשְׁמָהּ **קְטוּרָה**. **קְטוּרָה** דָא הִיא הָגָר. דְּהָא תָּנִינָן בָּתַר דְּאִתְפְּרָשָׁא הָגָר מִנֵּיהּ דְּאַבְרָהָם וְטָעַת בָּתַר גִּלּוּלֵי דְּאֲבוּהָ, לְבָתַר אִתְקַּשְׁרָא בְּעוֹבָדִין דְכַשְׁרָן, וּבְגִין כָּךְ אִשְׁתַּנֵּי שְׁמָהּ וְאִקְרֵי **קְטוּרָה** בְּעוֹבָדִין דְּכָשְׁרָן, וְשָׁדַר אַבְרָהָם וּנְסָבָהּ לֵיהּ לְאִנְתּוּ. מִכָּאן דְּשִׁנּוּי שְׁמָא מְכַפֵּר חוֹבִין, וְעַל דָּא אִשְׁתַּנֵּי שְׁמָהּ.

  ...**Ketura** is Hagar.  For behold, we've taught that after Hagar separated from Avram and strayed after her father's idols, later she cleaved to proper works, and that's why her name was changed and is called "**Ketura**" [incense i.e. rising straight] for upright deeds...

דף קלג ע"ב

- בְּנֵי הַפִּילַגְשִׁים, אִלֵּין הֲווּ בְּנֵי **קְטוּרָה** פִּלֶּגֶשׁ בְּקַדְמִיתָא וּפִלֶּגֶשׁ הַשְׁתָּא. רַבִּי חִיָּיא אָמַר פִּלַגְשִׁים מַמָּשׁ. וַיְשַׁלְּחֵם מֵעַל יִצְחָק בְנוֹ, דְּלָא לְשַׁלְּטָאָה לְגַבֵּיהּ דְּיִצְחָק. בְּעוֹדֶנוּ חַי, בְּעוֹד דְּהֲוָה אַבְרָהָם חַי וְקַיָּים בְּעַלְמָא דְּלָא יְקַטְרְגוּן לֵיהּ לְבָתַר, וּבְגִין דְּיִתְתַּקַּן יִצְחָק בִּסְטַר דִּינָא קַשְׁיָא עִלָּאָה לְאִתְתַּקְּפָא עַל כֻּלְּהוּ, וְכֻלְּהוּ אִתְכַּפְיָין קַמֵּיהּ. קֵדְמָה אֶל אֶרֶץ קֶדֶם, בְּגִין דְּתַמָּן אִינוּן סִטְרֵי חֳרָשֵׁי מְסָאֲבֵי.

   [Per R' Elazar?] the concubines' children are children of **Keturah**, who was a pilegesh before and a pilegesh now.  R' Chiyya says [No,] children of actual pilagshim...

===וישב===

דף קפו ע"ב

- תָּא חֲזֵי, כְּתִיב, (ישעיה מה) לֹא תֹהוּ בְּרָאָהּ לְשֶׁבֶת יְצָרָהּ, דְּקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא בְּגִין דָּא עֲבַד לֵיהּ לְבַר נָשׁ כְּדְקָא יְאוּת כְּדְאֲמָרָן. וְקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא עֲבַד טִיבוּ עִם עַלְמָא. תָּא חֲזֵי, מַה כְּתִיב, (בראשית כה) וַיּוֹסֶף אַבְרָהָם וַיִּקַּח אִשָּׁה וּשְׁמָהּ **קְטוּרָה**, רָזָא דְּנִשְׁמָתָא אָתַת לְאִתְתַּקָּנָא כְּמִלְקַדְּמִין.

   [A discussion of mitzva of procreation...] "Then
  again Avraham took a wife, and her name was **Keturah**." This is the secret of the
  soul coming back [in a body] to be repaired..

**==זוהר חדש==**

===יתרו===

זהר חדש נא ב

- מַה דְּלֵית הָכֵי בְּאַבְרָהָם, דְּנָפֵיק מִנֵּיהּ יִשְׁמָעֵאל וּבְנֵי **קְטוּרָה**, דְּאִינוּן סִיגֵי הַכֶּסֶף. וְאָדָם, דְּנָפַק מִנֵּיהּ קַיִן. וְנֹחַ, דְּנָפַק מִנֵּיהּ חָם. וְיִצְחָק, דְּנָפַק מִנֵּיהּ עֵשָׂו, סִיגֵי דַהֲבָא. אֲבָל יַעֲקֹב עַרְסֵיהּ שְׁלֵימָא אִיהוּ. וְעַל דָּא בֵּיהּ בָּחַר ה' מִכָּל הָעַמִּים. דִּכְתִיב, (תהלים קלה) כִּי יַעֲקֹב בָּחַר לוֹ יָהּ יִשְׂרָאֵל לִסְגֻלָּתוֹ, וּכְתִיב (דברים לב) כִּי חֵלֶק ה' עַמּוֹ יַעֲקֹב חֶבֶל נַחֲלָתוֹ. עַד כָּאן סִתְרֵי תּוֹרָה.

  This is not the case with Abraham [he was not "formed by God's hands"], as from him issued Ishmael and **Ketura**'s children, who are the dross of silver, and from Adam issued Kain... But Yaakob his "bed was whole" [...](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash%2C_Yitro.311?vhe=Zohar_Chadash&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

===בהר===

זהר חדש סא א

- רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן פְּתַח (משלי ח) לְהַנְחִיל אֹהֲבַי יֵשׁ וְאֹצְרֹתֵיהֶם אֲמַלֵּא. מַאי אֹהֲבַי, דָּא אַבְרָהָם, דְּאִתְּמָר בֵּיהּ (ישעיה מא) זֶרַע אַבְרָהָם אֹהֲבִי. אָמַר רִבִּי אֶלְעָזָר, אַבָּא אַבָּא, וְהָא יִשְׁמָעֵאל וּבְנֵי **קְטוּרָה** מִנֵּיהּ קָא אַתְיָין.
  בְּהַהוּא שַׁעֲתָא תָּמַהּ רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן, אַדְּהָכֵי אָתָא אֵלִיָּהוּ. אָמַר לֵיהּ,

  R' Shimon opened (Prov. 8:21), "To bequeath to those who love me, substance, and fill their treasuries."  Who are "those who love me?" This is Abraham, of whom it says (Isa. 41:8), "Seed of Abraham the one who loves me."  Said R' Elazar, "Aba, Aba -- But Ishmael and **Ketura**'s children issue from him!"  That moment R' Shimon was dumbstruck; meanwhile came Eliyahu, [and said to him...](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar_Chadash%2C_Behar.1?vhe=Zohar_Chadash&lang=bi)